# How to include plugin in cakephp view

Tags: cakephp

This error is raised while I call a captcha plugin php file into my view. But it works perfectly on my local host. How can I call this on my remote host?

> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required
>   '/hermes/waloraweb092/b275/moo.brandexponentscom/ivyscout/app/Plugin\Recaptcha\recaptchalib.php'
>   (include_path='/hermes/waloraweb092/b275/moo.brandexponentscom/ivyscout/lib:.:/usr/local/lib/php-5.2.17/lib/php')
>   in
>   /hermes/waloraweb092/b275/moo.brandexponentscom/ivyscout/app/View/Elements/provider_setting.ctp
>   on line 217

Comment: 1) Are you sure the file was uploaded correctly to your remote host? 2) How do you include it into the view? (Show your code)

Comment: Actually i tried to call google captcha in my view form. And this my code. require_once(APP.'Plugin\Recaptcha\recaptchalib.php');
echo '<div class="input text">'.recaptcha_get_html($publickey).'</div>';

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess: Your local system is from Bill Gates? also known as Microsoft?
This (as are some other OS) is a CI (case insensitive) OS.
Your deployment system is probably Linux and therefore CS (case sensitive).

You should pay more attention to the casing of your files and your App::uses() statements.
So its not `recaptchalib.php` but - if your class name is `RecaptchaLib` -

```
RecaptchaLib.php
```

Make sure both the file system and the code has the correct case and you will not run into problems on deployment.

So your `App::uses()` statement should be:

```
App::uses('RecaptchaLib', 'Recaptcha.Lib');
```

Assuming you loaded the plugin using `CakePlugin::load('Recaptcha')` and properly put the class file in the namespace where it should be, e.g. 'APP/Plugin/Recaptcha/Lib/'.

Last but not least on deployment you should clear the cache or temporary (seconds!) switch to debug mode > 0 to clear the cache this way. Otherwise the persistent cache will still have the old file system paths stored.

Comment: I just tried to call capcha lib file named recaptchalib.php. That file is collection function only. no class there. And this my code. require_once(APP.'Plugin\Recaptcha\recaptchalib.php');
echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);                                        Here i call the recaptcha_get_html() from recapchalib.php.

Comment: When it is a collection function only, never use App::uses(), use App::import(). The first only works for real classes. But i would advice you to rewrite it to a proper class to "justify" the namespacing here. Otherwise its just a vendor file or some bootstrapping stuff, not a /Lib file.

Comment: Hi Mark, Finally i found right plugin [link]https://github.com/tbsmcd/recaptcha_plugin[/link]. IT helps me to get captcha plugin. Anyway thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 0):

This should work anywhere on your app

require_once(CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH."/app/plugins/recaptchalib.php");